# Omnisharp build fails to find Microsoft.WebApplication.target, xbuild folder missing?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-code, mono, omnisharp

I'm trying to open and build the Linnworks SDK https://github.com/LinnSystems/LinnworksNetSDK in VSCode on Fedora Linux.  I think my problem is that a package is not installed or omnisharp hasn't located the build tooling, but I lack any experience of msbuild on Linux.

I installed the recommended C# extension for VSCode (v1.16.1 powered by Omnisharp) and followed the install instructions for .NET command line tools https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md which gave me the following Fedora packages:

```
Installing:
 dotnet-sdk-2.1           x86_64  2.1.402-1  packages-microsoft-com-prod  111 M
Installing dependencies:
 aspnetcore-runtime-2.1   x86_64  2.1.4-1    packages-microsoft-com-prod   29 M
 dotnet-host              x86_64  2.1.4-1    packages-microsoft-com-prod   45 k
 dotnet-hostfxr-2.1       x86_64  2.1.4-1    packages-microsoft-com-prod  195 k
 dotnet-runtime-2.1       x86_64  2.1.4-1    packages-microsoft-com-prod   27 M
 dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1  x86_64  2.1.4-1    packages-microsoft-com-prod  2.8 k
```

Opening the Linnworks SDK folder in VSCode showed Omnisharp doing a lot of good looking initialisation and build steps until hitting this error:

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/neek/workspace/LinnworksNetSDK/Linnworks/Example Applications/PluggableComponent/dotnet/Application/Application.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/neek/workspace/LinnworksNetSDK/Linnworks/Example Applications/PluggableComponent/dotnet/Application/Application.csproj'.
/home/neek/workspace/LinnworksNetSDK/Linnworks/Example Applications/PluggableComponent/dotnet/Application/Application.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "/home/neek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1/.omnisharp/1.32.5/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  /home/neek/workspace/LinnworksNetSDK/Linnworks/Example Applications/PluggableComponent/dotnet/Application/Application.csproj
```

So while loading `Application.csproj` it fails to find `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` in the expected location.  The .csproj file contains:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

It's resolving `VSToolsPath` to `/home/neek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1/.omnisharp/1.32.5/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0` which, sure enough, does not exist, my directories under `.vscode` end at the `mono` folder:

```
$ ls ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1/.omnisharp/1.32.5/lib/mono
4.5  gac
```

I have no idea where the `xbuild` folder is supposed to come from, so I tried to find possible locations:

```
$ locate Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v10.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v11.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v12.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v9.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
```

So I do have `xbuild` and the required `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`, just not at the expected location.  I tried hardcoding the path to my tools in the .csproj, replacing the other definition for it in the `PropertyGroup`:

```
<VSToolsPath>/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0</VSToolsPath>
```

But reloading the workspace, the build hit the same error as before, as if it's ignoring my `VSToolsPath` entirely.

Can anyone suggest what to try next? Should I be trying to point `VSToolsPath` somewhere else, to find `xbuild` on my system, or should `xbuild` actually be at the expected location under `.vscode` and I'm missing an installable package?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was forced to re-approach this issue, and with the newer tooling of the dotnet-sdk-2.2 and a few other changes, everything seems to 'just work' now.  I still don't have the files that were reported as missing, above, but this doesn't seem to be a problem any more, even if I check out the old version of the LinnworksNetSDK that I was using at the time and try rebuilding now.  There were some issues with the SDK that I resolved with the help of the support team at Linnworks but not related to the above build errors.

Comment: EDIT: ah no, those errors are still there, but they occur in projects I don't care about.  The SDK comes with about 4 example application projects, which seem to depend on .NET 4.5 and fail to build, and a bunch of Core 2.1 projects that do build (with a little tickling).  Something about my setup does still seem lacking.